# Converting maturities to numeric format

Tags: r, replace, type-conversion, substring

I am trying to make a function to replace weird looking maturities into numbers:

For a reproducable example: the following block contains the data.

```
dict <- c("ON","TN","1W","1M","2M","3M","6M","9M","1Y","1Y3M","1Y6M","1Y9M","2Y","2Y3M", "2Y6M","2Y9M","3Y","3Y3M","3Y6M","3Y9M","4Y","4Y3M","4Y6M","4Y9M","5Y","5Y3M","5Y6M","5Y9M","6Y","6Y3M","6Y6M","6Y9M","7Y","7Y3M","7Y6M","7Y9M","8Y","8Y3M","8Y6M","8Y9M","9Y","9Y3M","9Y6M","9Y9M","10Y","11Y","12Y","13Y","14Y","15Y","20Y","25Y","30Y","40Y","50Y")
```

I tried to think about it as follows:

- make a `sub()` function for the months (extract everything before M and after Y). Divide by 12.
- Then add this value to another sub that I call to extract the years.
- And then I guess a similar one for 0N (overnight so = `0`) & TN (tomorrow next, so `1/365`) although I would work with an if function for those? What do you think is most handy?

I was running this code. It correctly extracts the values after Y. Although it does not work for `10Y 11Y 12Y 13Y 14Y 15Y 20Y 25Y`... Anyone that can provide support?

```
sub("*.Y", "", dict)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  what would be the output for `1W` or `1Y3M`?

Comment: This is a little tricky because 1 week always has the same length, but months and years have slightly different days, and "tomorrow" is typically limited to business days, which vary on locality. You could come up with approximate numbers (ie where month = 30 days, for instance), but an exact solution requires more complicated logic.

Comment: Expected output for 1W should be 1/52 (in decimals). 1Y3M should be 15/12 (in decimals) 1 year and 3 months. Tried to make a manual function as well that replaces values in a dataframe that takes 1 element (data)... But sometimes there is not an element of the dict in the data object so that one failed as well (error)
data[data$GV4_TEXT == dict[2],] <- 1/365
  data[data$GV4_TEXT == dict[3],] <- 1/52
  data[data$GV4_TEXT == dict[4],] <- 1/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could replace the substring with `str_replace_all` and then `eval`uate

```
library(stringr)
setNames(sapply(trimws(str_replace_all(dict, c("ON" = "0",
    "TN" = "1/365", "W" = "*1/52", "M"="*1/12", "Y" = "*1+")), 
    whitespace = "\\+"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))), dict)
```

-output

```
          ON           TN           1W           1M           2M           3M           6M           9M           1Y         1Y3M 
 0.000000000  0.002739726  0.019230769  0.083333333  0.166666667  0.250000000  0.500000000  0.750000000  1.000000000  1.250000000 
        1Y6M         1Y9M           2Y         2Y3M         2Y6M         2Y9M           3Y         3Y3M         3Y6M         3Y9M 
 1.500000000  1.750000000  2.000000000  2.250000000  2.500000000  2.750000000  3.000000000  3.250000000  3.500000000  3.750000000 
          4Y         4Y3M         4Y6M         4Y9M           5Y         5Y3M         5Y6M         5Y9M           6Y         6Y3M 
 4.000000000  4.250000000  4.500000000  4.750000000  5.000000000  5.250000000  5.500000000  5.750000000  6.000000000  6.250000000 
        6Y6M         6Y9M           7Y         7Y3M         7Y6M         7Y9M           8Y         8Y3M         8Y6M         8Y9M 
 6.500000000  6.750000000  7.000000000  7.250000000  7.500000000  7.750000000  8.000000000  8.250000000  8.500000000  8.750000000 
          9Y         9Y3M         9Y6M         9Y9M          10Y          11Y          12Y          13Y          14Y          15Y 
 9.000000000  9.250000000  9.500000000  9.750000000 10.000000000 11.000000000 12.000000000 13.000000000 14.000000000 15.000000000 
         20Y          25Y          30Y          40Y          50Y 
20.000000000 25.000000000 30.000000000 40.000000000 50.000000000
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, you're super fast ;). Btw I get the output quite nicely: but for 1M to 50 years I get the output in months so I guess I just should divide them by 12? or how do I do this inside your function? :)

Comment: @FinancialRiskManagerBE Are you saying that `1M` should be `1/12`?, then what would be `1Y`

Comment: Indeed :) all should be in decimals. `1Y` should be `1`! So `7Y3M` should be `87/12` (87 months divided by 12).

Comment: @FinancialRiskManagerBE then, you need just the whole expression divided by 12?  updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @Akrun. Not the whole expression unfortunately. 1W should stay 1/52. TN should stay 1/365. I think those are the only 2 exceptions that make it harder

Comment: @FinancialRiskManagerBE what about now with the update.  This is one of the reasons to show the expected so that it can be crosschecked

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much Akrun! Will take the lesson with me for further posts!